# How to use if inside a command in bash script?

Tags: bash

I am writing a script in bash, and I have a problem with it:

```
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "1) Check Cassandra Status.")
         ssh skyusr@"$IP" "export JAVA_HOME=/opt/mesosphere && /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/*/frameworks/*/executors/*/runs/latest/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/bin/nodetool -p 7199 status" | sed -n '6,10p' | awk '{print $1,$2}' | DN="$(grep DN)" | [[if [[!DN]]; echo "All Good" else "Node(s) "$DN" is Down" ;fi]]
            ;;
        "2) Run Repair on all nodes.")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "3) Run Refresh on specific keyspace/Table.")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "4) Optional")
            echo "This option disabled"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

It gives me

> error:line 16: [[if: command not found

All was working until I added this if command, I need to echo a message if `$DN` is empty else echo another message .

Comment: I know, but i am using it inside a command line within a multichoice menu. it gives me this error:line 16: [[if: command not found

Comment: Yep, i misread it, deleted my comment.

Comment: Most of your code is not relevant for a minimal test case (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You make it easier if you edit your question to an mcve.

Comment: Is this still giving the error stated on line 16, even with the edits you made to the code? I can't see that this could be the case any more. 

What is the question following your edits to the code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about some of Bash's basic concepts like pipelines (`|`) versus compound commands (`if` and `[[`). For example `awk '{print $1,$2}' | DN="$(grep DN)"` does probably not do what you expect:

```
$ echo $'a\nb'
a
b

$ echo $'a\nb' | B=$(grep a)
$ echo $B
```

Note how the variable `B` is not set to `"a"`.

Furthermore your syntax `DN="$(grep DN)" | [[if [[!DN]]; echo "All Good"` is complete nonsense. You best start by reading some introduction. Then you can continue along the lines of:

```
A=$(....)
[[ -z $A ]] && echo "A is empty"
# or
if [[ -z $A ]] then echo "A is empty"; else echo "A is not empty"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` condition like below. Your `if` condition syntax is not correct and `then` part is also missing. I have just corrected the `if` condition rest you need to check again.

```
if [[ DN == "" ]]; then echo "All Good" else echo "Node(s) $DN is Down" ; fi
```